# How to keep existing line breaks in a function

Tags: java, string, word-wrap

I have a function that inserts a line break before a word when the sentence is longer than a given number :

```
public static String wrapString(String string, int charWrap)
{
    int lastBreak = 0;
    int nextBreak = charWrap;
    if (string.length() > charWrap)
    {
        String setString = "";
        do {
            while (string.charAt(nextBreak) != ' ' && nextBreak > lastBreak)
            {
                nextBreak--;
            }
            if (nextBreak == lastBreak)
            {
                nextBreak = lastBreak + charWrap;
            }
            setString += string.substring(lastBreak, nextBreak).trim() + "\n";
            lastBreak = nextBreak;
            nextBreak += charWrap;

        }
        while (nextBreak < string.length());
        setString += string.substring(lastBreak).trim();
        return setString;
    }
    else
    {
        return string;
    }
}
```

I send a sentence including line breaks already, so I would like this function not to count existing line breaks only as characters, but to reset the counting when it reaches a line break.

For example I send to the function the following : "En cas de paiement avant minuit, suivant la date d'apposition du présent avis, vous bénéficiez d'une minoration.\n Après le délai de 3 mois, un titre exécutoire sera adressé au titulaire."

It counts the char "\n" as a character so it cuts the next phrase earlier than it should.

Comment: What have you tried so far for this ?

Comment: Can you simplify with a short example

Comment: Try matching ascii code of char with 10 and 13 where 10 is for NL (\n)  and 13 is for CR (\r)

Comment: Maybe you could split your sentence by line break and apply your `wrapString` function to each line

Comment: @Oneiros , I think that should be the right way, but is there any existing function to split it so ?

Comment: @pocus Please update your example in the question itself

Comment: what is the purpose of `while (nextBreak < string.length());`?

Comment: @Lino , nextBreak is an int that define after how many characters the string should be cut, here we compare if the length of the string is not bigger than when it should be cut

Comment: @pocus I asked, because the `;` after the while will leave it with an empty body, so it *literally* does nothing and will loop forever

Comment: @pocus yes `String lines[] = string.split("[\\r?\\n]+");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split sentences from line breaks and then run your code for each of the strings. Finally concatenate all of the strings.

```
String para = "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc \n" +
            "abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc ";

String[] sentences = para.split("\n");
String finalString = "";
for (String s : sentences) {
    finalString = finalString + wrapString(s, 20).trim() + "\n";
}

System.out.println(finalString);
```

Comment: Prefer to use `StringBuilder` inside loops to increase performance.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Lino you are absolutely right. I was just trying to keep it simple

Comment: @Isuru Teaching/showing the wrong way to concatenate Strings in loops is not worth it to keep it "simple" IMO

Answer (score 0):

May be the below piece of code is what you are looking for :

```
public static String wrapString(String string, int charWrap)
{
int lastBreak = 0;
int nextBreak = charWrap;
if (string.length() > charWrap)
{
    String setString = "";
   int counter = 0; // create a counter to help you check each char if it is not a new line
    do {
        if(string.charAt(lastBreak+counter) == '\n' || 
        string.charAt(lastBreak+counter) == '\r') { 
        nextBreak = lastBreak + charWrap;
        setString += string.substring(lastBreak, nextBreak).trim() + "\n";
        lastBreak = nextBreak;
        counter = 0;// if it is a new line change counter back to zero
        }
        if(counter == charWrap) { // if counter has reached max range to split without finding any new line character, proceed with normal process of injecting new line)
         nextBreak = lastBreak+counter; 
        while (string.charAt(nextBreak) != ' ' && nextBreak > lastBreak)
        {
            nextBreak--;
        }
        if (nextBreak == lastBreak)
        {
            nextBreak = lastBreak + charWrap;
        }
        counter = 0;
        setString += string.substring(lastBreak, nextBreak).trim() + "\n";
        lastBreak = nextBreak;
        }
        counter ++;

    }
    while ((counter+lastBreak) < string.length());
    setString += string.substring(lastBreak).trim();
    return setString;
}
else
{
    return string;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it ends into an infinite loops, my program stops responding after a while

Comment: @Lino I have already  shared comments whereever I have update to explain what I have done

Comment: @pocus Can you try now and let me know if it helps